# Rolle's Theorem and error bound formula for trapezoidal rule

Tags: calculus, numerical-methods, upper-lower-bounds, rolles-theorem

In [these notes](https://www.macmillanlearning.com/studentresources/highschool/mathematics/rogawskiapet2e/additional_proofs/error_bounds_proof_for_numerical_integration.pdf) on error bounds
for numerical
integration,
it shows proofs for the error bound formula for the midpoint rule and the trapezoidal rule.

I don't understand the last part (page 5-6) for the trapezoidal rule.

1. What's the point of using Rolle's theorem?
2. Why does he suddenly use a $G(x)$ function with that "$q(...)$" ?
3. More specifically, what's the goal of using $G''(x) = 0\,$?

https://www.macmillanlearning.com/studentresources/highschool/mathematics/rogawskiapet2e/additional_proofs/error_bounds_proof_for_numerical_integration.pdf

Comment: I'm trying to understsand with the help of desmos : https://www.desmos.com/calculator/rh7dd6jogs    G(x) is at line 21.

Comment: Well, I guess I'm starting to understand,  if I zoom into G(x) on the interval, there's indeed 3 zeroes. Setting G''(x) to 0 isolates "q" and f''(x).